# Extracting an item from a real game inside a comic

Tags: intellectual-property, fair-use

Suppose I make a webcomic, where at some point one of the characters wields a portal gun, similar to the one in Valve's "Portal"; in fact, the point is that this gun, in the comic universe, is literally extracted from the game (with magic or something like it). Can I legally do that, without getting a permission from Valve? If not, is there a realistic way to ask for such permission?

So far, I figured I won't be taking money from Valve, even if they start to sell their own comics (the story is original, it's not a full Portal fanfic), and the use seems transformative (again, the story is original and not really about Portal universe). On the other hand, the gun itself, while being a small part, is also a crucial part of the Portal games, so, the portion used is going to be a significant one.

Comment: we can't figure that out for you, talk to your lawyer or contact the rightsholder. The Portal gun is not small, it is the *hinging part* of the games, and iconic. Often it or its portals are used to refer to the game in commentary.

Comment: True, that's why I'm worried. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be easy to "contact the rightsholder".